# python slowing down every minute or so on windows

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a clean windows pc, with just python and the bear minimum installed. the problem i am facing is that every 3/4 minutes the execution of my python code slows down by a factor of 3 for a few seconds. it looks like the OS is taking some CPU Power away from python. Its not affected by any specified function, it just happens randomly, wherever it is located. The app uses Qthreads and it is always just one of these threads that is affected. (not always the same thread tough...) the other threads keep working like normal.

How can I track down the root cause of this and solve it?

Comment: I would suspect your code has locking issues, probably  not OS related. Do your threads use locks directly? Mutexes? Maybe you could add code to print when locks are used

Comment: Also keep in mind that Qt runs its own event loop to process signals, but python code (running on CPython) is still only able to run while locking the GIL

Comment: Thank you. Sorry i startet coding python only recently, noob here... could you please elaborate your sugeations? Thank you

Comment: The [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) is part of CPython and PyPy which prevents more than one thread from running Python code at once. Let's say you have a Qt signal that runs a python function, that function can't start executing until python code in all other threads stops or is interrupted